# What is the possible solution for Laravel 5 havingRaw query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
$sql = 'AG.int_partner_key, PA.`tx_partner_name` AS partner_name, rs.*,count(p.park_id) as park_count, p.reason, p.remark,'
        . 'p.created_at as parked_time, su.name as parked_by,'
        . 'su.name AS locked_by';
        $rows = DB::table('raw_subscribers as rs')                                         
        ->join('parks as p','p.raw_subscriber_id','=','rs.raw_subscriber_id')                
        ->join('users as pu','pu.user_id','=','p.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('outreach_partner_agents as AG','AG.tx_agent_id','=','rs.health_worker_id')
        ->leftJoin('outreach_partners as PA','PA.int_outreach_partner_key','=','AG.int_partner_key')
        ->leftJoin('subscriber_locks as sl','sl.raw_subscriber_id','=','rs.raw_subscriber_id')
        ->leftJoin('users as su','su.user_id','=','sl.user_id')
        ->select(DB::raw($sql.' AG.int_partner_key as partner_id'))
        ->where('rs.verification_status','=','PARKED')
        ->whereRaw('p.call_time is NULL');

        $rows = $rows->orderBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(p.created_at,'%Y-%m-%d')"))
            ->groupBy('rs.raw_subscriber_id')
            ->havingRaw('AG.int_partner_key=14')
            ->orderBy('park_count','DESC')                
            //->toSql();
            ->paginate(50);
```

Error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'AG.int_partner_key' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `raw_subscribers` as
But if I use toSql() to get the query and run the query in sql editor its works fine. I am not understand what is the problem with the query.

Comment: try this `->havingRaw('partner_id=14')`

Comment: my field name is int_partner_key

Comment: but you alias the field name

Comment: I did it like `$sql = 'AG.int_partner_key AS partner_id , ...` and 
`->havingRaw('partner_id=14')`

Comment: but still i got the same error